# How to add attributes to PrimeNG's slidemenu backlabel property?

Tags: angular, primeng

Using PrimeNG for native Angular UI components, there is a menu called "slidemenu", which has a useful property called "backLabel".  That property ultimately creates a button for navigating back to a previous view.  However, the back button that is generated is skipped when tabbing through the page.

My idea is to add the "tabindex" attribute to the element, however, I can't figure out a way to do that, I don't see any documentation on primeNG that shows how.

The angular component looks like:

`<p-slideMenu backLabel="Back" [model]="items" [menuWidth]="337"></p-slideMenu>`

When it's generated it looks like: 
    `<span class="ng-classname">Back</span>`

I know I can access the css with `span.ng-classname` as the selector but I don't see anyway of adding attributes to the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `renderer2` on a reference to your p-slideMenu component, and then access the backward ElementRef:

```html
<p-slideMenu #myMenu></p-slideMenu>
```

then, on your component containing the slide menu:

```js
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SlideMenu } from 'primeng/slidemenu';

// (somewhere in your code where is needed)
//...
@ViewChild('myMenu') slider: SlideMenu;
//...
this.slider.renderer.setAttribute(this.slider.backward.nativeElement, 'tabindex', '1');
```

This way you will get the tabindex attribute set on the backward control of the slidemenu. You should include it at the proper time (i.e. when slider is fully displayed). You may need to do some cleanup actions (such as on destroy, etc). depending on your expected behavior on your code, etc.